# How to add payment method programmatically with Google Payments API?

Tags: google-api, google-play, google-play-developer-api

Other than simulating a user filling the necessary details on the https://payments.google.com/manage/?referer=https://support.google.com/payments/answer/6220309?hl%3Den#CreateInstrumentPlace: page, is there an API for programmatically adding a payment method to Google Play/Google Payments?